# Regex: find files of X extension from Y folder

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to filter files from the `node_modueles` or `vendor` folders that have `.js` extension.

Here is how I find files from those folders:

```
/[\\/]vendor|node_modules[\\/]/
```

Works like a charm. Here is how I find JavaScript files:

```
/\.(js)$/
```

The above works as well. Now when I try to combine the two:

```
/(?=[\\/]vendor|node_modules[\\/])(?=\.(js)$)/
```

It breaks everything.

Comment: Looks like th solution is: `[\\/]vendor|node_modules[\\/](?=.*\.js$)`

Comment: Your regex matches (a slash or a backslash followed by vendor) OR (node_modules followed by slash or bakslash followed by `something.js` Are you sure that does the job? Could you show some examples that must match and some that mustn't? See: https://regex101.com/r/wQPDMi/1

Comment: @Toto, you're rigth - I missed the brackets. The result should be `[\\/](vendor|node_modules)[\\/](?=.*\.js$)`.

Comment: The lookahead is useless, @hainan answer is the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it on https://regex101.com/

```
[\\/](vendor|node_modules)[\\/].+\.js$
```